# Kafka throwing error after updating Avro spring boot

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, avro, spring-messaging

So i updated my avro with a default int attribute

```
{
  "name": "minimum",
  "type": [
    "null",
    "int"
  ],
  "default": null
}
```

On the schema registry i have it set to forward compatibility.

My consumer exists in the same project as the producer so is using the same generated avro. while testing i noticed now the consumer is throwing the following error :

```
org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot handle message; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot convert from [org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData$Record] to [com.example.dto.CarDto] for GenericMessage [payload={....}
```

I have checked the config and it has the followng set:

```
spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer=io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.specific.avro.reader=true
```

There are no dev tools, and im using spring boot 2.5

UPDATE:
This has nothing to do with updating the avro file, i didnt notice but the exception was being suppressed. And i change i made now logs this.
So my question still stands, some threads have said its because the avro class is in a different package?

my structure is:

src->main->avro->Car.avsc

src->main->java->com->example->dto->CarDto.java

src->main->java->com->example->configs->producer/consumer

src->main->java->com->example->service->ConsumerProcessor.java

my config

```
    @Slf4j
@Configuration
public class ConsumerConfig {

    @Value("${kafka.bootstrapAddress}")
    private String bootstrapAddress;


    @Value("${kafka.schemaRegistryUrl}")
    private String schemaRegistryUrl;

    // Consumers Configs

    private Map<String, Object> getConsumerProps() {
        final var props = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "topic-a");
        props.put(AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, schemaRegistryUrl);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);

        return props;
    }

    private <T, K> ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<K, T> getConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory(final ConsumerFactory<K, T> kafkaConsumerFactory, final KafkaTemplate<K, T> template) {
        final ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<K, T> factory =
                new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(kafkaConsumerFactory);

        factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
        return factory;
    }

    private KafkaAvroDeserializer getAvroDeserializer() {
        final var deserializerProps = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        deserializerProps.put(AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, schemaRegistryUrl);
        deserializerProps.put(KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.SPECIFIC_AVRO_READER_CONFIG, "true");
        final var deserializer = new KafkaAvroDeserializer();
        deserializer.configure(deserializerProps, false);
        return deserializer;
    }


    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Integer, com.exmaple.dto.CarDto> dataKafkaListenerContainerFactory(
            final ConsumerFactory<Integer, com.example.dto.CarDto> kafkaConsumerFactory,
            final KafkaTemplate<Integer, com.example.dto.CarDto> template) {
        return getConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory(kafkaConsumerFactory, template);
    }

    @Bean("kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    public ConsumerFactory<Integer, com.example.dto.CarDto> dataConsumerFactory() {
        final Map<String, Object> props = getConsumerProps();
        final KafkaAvroDeserializer deserializer = getAvroDeserializer();

        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props, new IntegerDeserializer(), new ErrorHandlingDeserializer(deserializer));
    }
}
```

Here is my avro

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": “CarDto”,
  "namespace": "com.example.dto",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": “id”,
      "type": [
        "null",
        "int"
      ],
      "default": null
    },   
       {
      "name": "minimum",
      "type": ["null", {"type": "int", "logicalType": "date"}],
      "default": null
    }
  ]
}
```

my consumer

```
@Slf4j
@Service
public class dataConsumer implements AvroKafkaConsumer<CarDto> {

    Integer counter = 0;

    @Override
    @KafkaListener(topics = “topic-a”, containerFactory = “dataKafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    public void listen(final CarDto carDto, final Acknowledgment acknowledgment) {

        acknowledgment.acknowledge();
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return “data”;
    }
}
```

So i noticed that the containerFactory is named something different to in the consumer service. "dataKafkaListenerContainerFactory" does that matter?

while in the config its

```java
@Bean("kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    public ConsumerFactory<Integer, com.example.dto.CarDto> dataConsumerFactory() {
```

SO i did some clean up and removed methods and added the following

```
 private Map<String, Object> getProps() {
     final var props = new HashMap<String, Object>();
 ……. existing props

     props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, Integer.class);
     props.put(KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.SPECIFIC_AVRO_READER_CONFIG, true);
     props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ErrorHandlingDeserializer.class);
     props.put(ErrorHandlingDeserializer.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS, KafkaAvroDeserializer.class);


     return props;
 }

 @Bean
 public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Integer, CarDto> myKafkaContainerFactory() {
     final ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Integer, CarDto> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
     factory.setConsumerFactory(kafkaConsumerFactory());
     factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
     return factory;
 }

 public ConsumerFactory<Integer, CarDto> kafkaConsumerFactory() {
     final Map<String, Object> props = getProps();
     final KafkaAvroDeserializer deserializer = new KafkaAvroDeserializer();

     return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props, new IntegerDeserializer(), new ErrorHandlingDeserializer(deserializer));
 }
```

Comment: How is the Java class generated?

Comment: What do you mean "different package"? `com.exmple.service` can import from `com.example.dto` just fine. Your error isn't a compilation one, only runtime deserialization, so the imports are fine.

Comment: @OneCricketeer i was reading some other threads they mentioned that it could be class loader issue or the way the class is being created. But im still not sure why its causing an issue

Comment: @NicPegg via gradle plugin.. it auto generates the class.

Comment: I don't think that's the case. You could rewrite the same consumer without spring, and packages would be fine. Please show a [mcve] of your Spring app

Comment: @OneCricketeer hi i have added my configuration for consumer

Comment: You seem to be missing `KafkaAvroDeserializer<CarDto>` types

Comment: @OneCricketeer how do i create one... i have the final KafkaAvroDeserializer deserializer = getAvroDeserializer(); .. how do i add the types?

Comment: Add the angle brackets, as shown

Comment: @OneCricketeer dont think thats possible .. Type 'io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer' does not have type parameters

Comment: I also noticed should i have my data consumer named "kafkaListenerContainerFactory" should that be right?

Comment: `@Bean("kafkaListenerContainerFactory")` - the consumer factory should not have that name. You can't have 2 beans with the same name; it collides with the proper name for the container factory. You can use a different name for the container factory, as long as you specify it on the `@KafkaListener`.

Comment: @GaryRussell i have made the change and still the same error persists. Im kinda lost as to how to get around this.

Comment: I can't help with the avro stuff; I was just pointing out that your bean names were messed up. You still seem to be calling the consumer factory `kafkaListenerContainerFactory` which makes no sense. But now your container factory matches the name in the `@KafkaListener`, so that should be ok - but this has nothing to do with the avro deserializer creating a `GenericData$Record` - maybe run it in a debugger?

Comment: @GaryRussell Thanks, so i did some clean up and now its working. Im still not sure why i needed all those additional properties, but its all working now. Im new to kafka so not 100%, but i was reading other example configs which had all these set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edited the config

```
 private Map<String, Object> getProps() {
     final var props = new HashMap<String, Object>();
 ……. existing props

     props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, Integer.class);
     props.put(KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.SPECIFIC_AVRO_READER_CONFIG, true);
     props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ErrorHandlingDeserializer.class);
     props.put(ErrorHandlingDeserializer.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS, KafkaAvroDeserializer.class);


     return props;
 }

 @Bean
 public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Integer, CarDto> myKafkaContainerFactory() {
     final ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Integer, CarDto> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
     factory.setConsumerFactory(kafkaConsumerFactory());
     factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
     return factory;
 }

 public ConsumerFactory<Integer, CarDto> kafkaConsumerFactory() {
     final Map<String, Object> props = getProps();
     final KafkaAvroDeserializer deserializer = new KafkaAvroDeserializer();

     return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props, new IntegerDeserializer(), new ErrorHandlingDeserializer(deserializer));
 }
```

Comment: You may want to call `deserializer.configure(props)`

Comment: @OneCricketeer what does that do? And is that needed if the consumer factory is also have the same values set.

Comment: It passes `KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig` values to the deserializer instance directly rather than to the consumer properties from the factory